# How to fill an area with a specific colour in PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing

I am creating an application that allows you to take a photo and then fill parts of that photo with other colours. Similar to what photoshop does. The idea is that someone can get an idea what their room would look like if it was painted a specific colour.

1. Which PHP toolkit/library can I use to do this?
2. Is there a better PHP library available that could allow for a smarter way to achieve this?
3. Is this fantasy even possible? Or would I be better off rather focusing on fixed set of sample images that allow you to only replace those specific ones?

I was able to do a simple colour replacement using [imagefilter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php), but this would only replace colours with an exact match. I need a bit more of a brain behind it so that it works like photoshops "fill" tool, where you can specifiy a 100% of "leniency". Is imagefilter the right job for the task?

Comment: Well its possible, but it will require more than only 5 lines of code. You could try `imagecolorset()`. You can specify a palette of colors in this function. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorset.php If that doesnt work, you can use GD+ for more advanced image processing.

Comment: You do expect php to have much more built-in things than it's normal. You would need to compare different rgb sets